# My recent app got rejected because of android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions, user-permissions

My recent app got rejected because of android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES because of play policy how to get arround with it.
without removing te permissions my app needs it to perform certain functions.

I tried to appeal again but still not approved.

Comment: [We cannot help you with Play Store policy concerns](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic). If you want to learn how to avoid needing that permission, perhaps ask a separate Stack Overflow question showing what you are doing where you feel that you need `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES`.

Comment: I am basically makaing a personalised app manager where users can see all the installed app on their device so thats why i need the permissions.

Comment: Help me in accordance with google play policies their many app  like there in play store in this niche how come their apps getting approved and mine is rejected what am i supposed to de to correct the problem